# How to enable javascript in smart search field of safari ios 7 on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios7, bookmarklet

We can enable javascript execution in the smart search field (navigation bar) of Safari on Mac OS X for desktop, but how can we enable it in the Safari on iPhone? There's no such option in the Safari's configuration of iPhone.

Or, if that is totally forbidden on iPhone and can't no be configured, then how can we use a bookmarklet on Safari of iOS 7 on iPhone?

Comment: I think you mean 'Safari on a desktop?'

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that iOS will let you put javascript in the smart search bar, but you can create bookmark lets, sort of. Unfortunately, you need to add them on OS X and have them sync.

Here is a guide to create one for the popular web-comic XKCD for example. [XKCD Descriptions inline](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100404045906105)

Also, this would have probably been a better question for the http://superuser.com stack exchange site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, unfortunately it does't work for Safari of iOS7 on a iPhone. I've tried to create a simple bookmarklet in Safari of OS X as javascript: alert(123); and then sync to Safari of iOS on my iPhone, but there wasn't any alert window showing when bookmark was selected.

Furthermore, when I turned on the Web inspector option of the iOS Safari, and connected it with my OS X Safari. I could execute the javascript in the debug console with the alert window popping out.

Comment: In fact, even in the Safari of OS X Maverick, we need to turn on the Develop menu and then select the "Allow javascript in smart search field". But in the Safari of iOS7, there's no Develop menu at all ...